# RxJava: Using combineLatest with 3 different streams in Kotlin

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 3 calls that I want to combine so that I can stop my loading animation after fetching all the data. Do I need to put 3 observables into some kind of wrapper?

**EDIT:** The emphasis of this question is that I'm not sure about the combine function. Although I'd like to thank you kindly for your answers, I was not asking what operator I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function3 can be used to combine 3 observables.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Rx Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) Operator

Wrap them using zip, and write zipper method for how you want those combined data.

**Note: If any of observable throws error then, it will be treated as an error of whole chain.**